# How to get array elements which match variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filter

I have an array like this:

```
var numbers = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven"];
```

Now I need to create a new array according to this variable:

```
var search;
```

---

EX1:

```
var search = 'f';
```

I want this:

```
var matches = ['four','five'];
```

---

EX2:

```
var search = 'fi';
```

I want this:

```
var matches = ['five'];
```

---

EX3:

```
var search = 'fig';
```

I want this:

```
var matches = []; // empty
```

---

How can I do that?

Comment: With a for loop that uses indexOf() on each array item?

Comment: Do you need the substring to be matched in the exact same way? I mean, do you need var search = "fie" to match the value "five" as well?

Comment: There are numerous array methods that can be used for this. Please show what you tried. Also clarify what constitutes a match. Does `t` match `fifteen`?

Comment: sounds like you want us to do your homework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter`:

```
numbers.filter(function(x){ if(x.indexOf(search) >= 0) return x })
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lj1tc7pw/)

Comment: this is actually wrong. doesn't meet all edge cases.

Comment: @self: as I've understood, it is the intended behaviour

Comment: @self Why do you think it doesn't meet all edge cases?

Answer (score 2):

you can use concept like this:

```
var numbers = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven"];

var matches = [];

var search = 'f';
var sl=search.length;

for(i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){

  if(numbers[i].substring(0,sl)===search){

       matches.push(numbers[i]);
    }

}
```